# Operations on xml file using Swift for mobile

Tags: ios, swift, xml

I have to do some operations in  my xml file in project
Operations like -

> Inserting the records
>
> Writing the records
>
> Deleting the records at specific location(with index).

NSXMLDocument is for Mac OS

Can any one help me with some sample code to understand and to implement the operations on the Xml file without using the third party frameworks.

Comment: for iOS you can use TouchXML from https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML

Comment: @CodeChanger is touchXml is a third part framework?

Comment: If this is your document and you own it, maybe it would be better to switch to json since the built-in support for json is so good now in swift

Comment: yes its 3rd party framework.

Comment: https://github.com/craiggrummitt/SwiftXML

Comment: @CodeChanger can't use third part frameworks

Comment: @3000 Thank you for the answer Tried your solution. But it is just printing the modified xml I need to make changes in the XMlfile means it should effect the respective Xml file and can see the visible changes in the file.

Comment: @sireesha: that is a completely different thing: to read/write a file you need another API: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-save-a-string-to-a-file-on-disk-with-writeto

Answer (score 0):

For iOS Apple provides an [XMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparser) api for swift and NSXMLParser for Objective C. You can check out [this](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/parse-xml-ios-tutorial) tutorial for reference.

You can use following code to read a file in iOS

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("data", ofType: "json")
let content = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(path) as String
```

then pass the string to XMLParser and implement its delegate methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sireesha for that without a 3rd party api you will have to write a serialise function in your model class which would convert all your properties to xml string